# Cannot handle jquery custom event on Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, web-component

I have created web components custom element with shadow dom and i am using custom element inside Meteor template. I am trying to trigger and handle jquery custom event in web components custom element but i couldn't. Meteor loads jquery v1.11.2 and custom element uses jquery v2.1.4. I have tried not to use jquery in custom element and I have changed jquery version to v1.11.2 from v2.1.4 in custom element but the result is the same, i could not handle event.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor wraps functions in templates so that it has a limited scope. 
To give the code a global scope so it is actually called, you have 2 options: declare the variables and functions without the 'var' keyword, or put your code into a  tag inside the HTML template.